# Are you allowed to use saved interest money to pay interest?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, riba

Are you allowed to use interest money that you gained from saving accounts towards paying the interest fees for a mortgage?

The mortgage consists of money I have borrowed to buy a house AND interest money imposed by the bank. If I use my halal work earnings to pay for the cost of the house and use the bank savings interest money to pay for the mortgage interest- would then be allowed? Using interest to pay interest?

Answer (score 1):

As much as i know, most of interests are riba, and apparently there might be some interests who are paid by the Islamic banks, but the important point is that the contract of Islamic bank should have some specific Islamic rules to make those interests halal otherwise this would be riba and haram.

you also should know that haram is haram. then if this interest is haram, its using can be haram too.

Answer (score -1):

No. The interest received has to be paid off in charitable funds
http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90769

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you pay off the loan from the amount you've put in savings? The money you're earning from the savings account (you gave money on rent) is riba, it's haraam.